# Have any muggle used an enchanted tool or entered an enchanted place before?

Tags: harry-potter

In the Harry Potter books, I don't recall any mention of a muggle accessing an enchanted building or place or even using a magical object. If a wizard allows it, can muggles enter an enchanted building such as Hogwarts or leaky cauldron? I know squibs can, but they are descendants of wizards and they can also see dementors while muggles can't.

Comment: In _Fantastic Beasts_ Jacob entered MACUSA; I think Muggle parents enter Platform 9.75, and it's enchanted as well.

Comment: At least the first part (and probably the second) is a duplicate. Also, these are two separate questions. Could you edit to focus on one?

Comment: Never mind, this is a duplicate of the question about whether a Muggle can use magical objects, as well as many separate questions about whether Muggles can access magical places (of which I linked the two you mention, and one other obvious one).

Comment: @Adamant - No point, really. It's turtles (dupes) all the way down